# how to upload an image in comments?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i have a small form in my blog detail view and it has a name,last name,email and an image field. the first three work fine but when i add the imagefield in the form, the form wont save from the page but it works from admin page.
this is my views.py:

```
def campaign_detail_view(request, id):
    template_name = 'gngo/campaign-detail.html'
    campaign = get_object_or_404(Campaign, id = id)
    comments = CampaignForm.objects.filter(campaign=campaign).order_by('-id')
    form = FormCamp(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():
            name = request.POST.get('name')
            last = request.POST.get('last')
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            comment = CampaignForm.objects.create(campaign=campaign,name=name,last=last,email=email)
            comment.save()
            return redirect('campaign-detail',id=id)
        else:
            form = FormCamp()
    context = {
        'campaign':campaign,
        'comments':comments,
        'form':form,
    }
    context["object"] = Campaign.objects.get(id = id)
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

and this is my comment model:

```
class CampaignForm(models.Model):
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
```

this is a non user form, so everyone can fill it. please help me understand how to add the ability to upload an image in this form

oh and this the form:

```
class FormCamp(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = CampaignForm
         fields = ('name','last','email', 'image',)
```

THANKS ALOT FOR THE ANSWERS AND SUPPORTS

Comment: Where is the image field?

Comment: imagine there is one

Comment: Without sharing what you have tried it's hard to give an answer...

Comment: there you go! i fixed it. but i dont know what to add in views for the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the form to validate and then manually extracting the fields again, you should use the `save` method of your `ModelForm` and pass `request.FILES` to your form when creating it.

And as the campaign is not an editable field, it shall be added after creating the object.

```py
def campaign_detail_view(request, id):
    template_name = 'gngo/campaign-detail.html'
    campaign = get_object_or_404(Campaign, id = id)
    comments = CampaignForm.objects.filter(campaign=campaign).order_by('-id')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormCamp(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            campaign_form = form.save(commit=False)
            campaign_form.campaign = campaign
            campaign_form.save()
            return redirect('campaign-detail',id=id)
    else:
        form = FormCamp()

    context = {
        'campaign':campaign,
        'comments':comments,
        'form':form,
    }
    context["object"] = Campaign.objects.get(id = id)
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#the-view

Comment: it gives me this error when i do  this...NOT NULL constraint failed: gngo_campaignform.campaign_id

Comment: @sam I didn't take attention that the campaign is not included in the form, please try this updated version.

Comment: the error is gone but it wont save the form... im so sorry about this please help me

Comment: @sam Sorry, I also forgot to add request.FILES at form submission... Edited to show it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def campaign_detail_view(request, id):
    template_name = 'gngo/campaign-detail.html'
    campaign = get_object_or_404(Campaign, id = id)
    comments = CampaignForm.objects.filter(campaign=campaign).order_by('-id')
    form = FormCamp(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment = CampaignForm.objects.create(campaign=campaign,name=name,last=last,email=email)
            comment = request.FILES['image'] 
            comment.save()
            return redirect('campaign-detail',id=id)
    else:
            form = FormCamp()
context = {
    'campaign':campaign,
    'comments':comments,
    'form':form,
}
context["object"] = Campaign.objects.get(id = id)
return render(request, template_name, context)

class FormCamp(forms.ModelForm): to this;
class FormCamp(forms.Form):
```

Don't forget to add enctype=multipart/form-data in your form in template.

Comment: it tells me that the name 'name' is not defined

Comment: @Sam.. Where is your error pointing at on template? Check it and let me know

Comment: ok it saves but it gives me this error about the image:
'TemporaryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'save'
the name,last and email save correctly

Comment: @Sam.. I just updated my answer, check if it still show same error.

Comment: yeah it still shows the same 'TemporaryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'save' error

Comment: I added these 3 lines because of the last error which was that the name is not defined:
name = request.POST.get('name')
last = request.POST.get('last')
email = request.POST.get('email')
then it gave me the TemporaryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'save' error

Comment: @Sam.. Change this class FormCamp(forms.ModelForm): to class FormCamp(forms.Form): tell me what you got.

Comment: i dont think that this is the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210527/discussion-between-oghomwen-oguns-and-sam).